# How to find this element and change html Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with Chrome addon.

How to find this element and get value 12752. I can't do that by class becouse it's reapeatible and I can't change HTML code.

```
<span class="tip_trigger" data-original-title="Some text" onclick="copyTextToClipboard('12752')">12752</span>
```

then I need to change onclick to not to copy to clipboard but to open a link in new tab.

Everything what i tried doesn't work

Comment: Do you own that Chrome Extension code?

Comment: _"I can't do that by class becouse it's reapeatible"_ - okay, so then what about this element _is_ unique? If the `copyTextToClipboard` in the onclick attribute makes it unique enough to find, then use an attribute-value-starts-with selector, `'[onclick^=copyTextToClipboard]`.

Comment: Do you have the code for `copyTextToClipboard(str)`? If yes, then show it here.

Comment: @CBroe unfortunatelly I have two elements found but I need only one value:
` var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[onclick^=copyTextToClipboard]') `

`<span class="tip_trigger pointer" data-original-title="Kopiuj do schowka" onclick="copyTextToClipboard('651117598')">651117598</span>`
`<span class="tip_trigger" data-original-title="Kopiuj do schowka" onclick="copyTextToClipboard('12752')">12752</span>`

Comment: Then you need to find an additional criterion, that will allow you to limit the selection to the "correct" one.

Comment: Will you always be targetting the second of the two? If so, you can use `[onclick^=copyTextToClipboard]:nth-child(2)`. Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/65rhvp8f/).